# C# List FindAll with reflection

Tags: c#, list, reflection

I have a struct with a lot of members. I need to filter grid.
Now i have something like this :

```
foreach(string word in words)
{
    if (c.Caption == "ID") 
        FilteredList.AddRange(BaseList.FindAll(x => x.ID == Int32.Parse(word)));
    else if (c.Caption == "Serial"
        FilteredList.AddRange(BaseList.FindAll(x => x.Serial == word));
    else if (c.Caption == "Phone")
        FilteredList.AddRange(BaseList.FindAll(x => x.Phone == word));
    etc...
}
```

Is it possible to create something like this ?

```
 foreach(string word in words)
 {
     var propertyInfo = object.GetType().GetMember(word);
     FilteredList.AddRange(BaseList.FindAll(x => x.propertyInfo == word));    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
foreach(string word in words)
{
    var propertyInfo = object.GetType().GetMember(word);
    FilteredList.AddRange(BaseList.FindAll(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x) == word));    
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Reflection doesn't quite work here because you have a special case - `ID`. If `c.Caption` is `ID`, you would call `int.Parse` before comparing. This makes using reflection directly quite difficult.

If that special case does not exist, and you only have `string` properties to compare, then you can do this:

```
 foreach(string word in words)
 {
     var propertyInfo = object.GetType().GetProperty(word);
     FilteredList.AddRange(BaseList.FindAll(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x) == word));    
 }
```

To handle the special case, you can create a method that compares two arbitrarily typed objects:

```
public bool CustomEquals(object o1, object o2) {
    if (o1 is int && o2 is string) {
        return o1 == int.Parse((string)o2);
    }
    // handle other special cases here...
    return o1 == o2;
}

// usage:
FilteredList.AddRange(BaseList.FindAll(x => CustomEquals(propertyInfo.GetValue(x), word)));
```

Comment: Hello, it's impossible to use x in propertyInfo.GetValue(x)

Comment: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @devio95 My bad. Fixed.

Comment: Nope :/ I need GetMember() instead of GetProperty() and with GetMember() propertyInfo.GetValue(x) doesn't work

Comment: @devio95 Why `GetMember`? Are you trying to compare things that are not properties? What are they?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `BaseList` is a *generic collection* declared like

```
  // Any collection with 1st Generic type being item's type
  List<SomeClass> BaseList = ...
```

We can look for the property:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;

  ...

  var property = BaseList      // Given a collection...
    .GetType()
    .GetGenericArguments()[0]  // Get collection's item type 
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(prop => 
        prop.CanRead &&                  // readable  
       !prop.GetGetMethod().IsStatic &&  // not static
        prop.GetGetMethod().IsPublic &&  // public
       (typeof(IConvertible)).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)) // convertable
    .FirstOrDefault(prop => string.Equals(prop.Name, c.Caption));  // of given name
```

And then read the `property`s value and compare it with *converted* `word`:

```
  if (property != null) {
    foreach(string word in words) {
      FilteredList.AddRange(BaseList.FindAll(item => 
        // convert given string (word) to property value's type
        // and compare
        object.Equals(Convert.ChangeType(word, property.PropertyType), 
                      property.GetValue(item)))); 
  }
  else {
    // Property not found
  }
```